# Full height using flex-direction: column

Tags: html, css

I want my c1 to be fully stretched, but I wonder why when I apply flex:1 it doesn't fill up the space.

```css
.wrap {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.c1 {
  background: red;
  flex: 1;
}

.c2 {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
  <div class='c1'>
    <div>child 1</div>
    <div>more content</div>
   </div>
  <div class='c2'>child 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to set a height on the parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your wrap class you have to add the height.

```css
.wrap {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.c1 {
  background: red;
  flex: 1;  
}

.c2 {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
  <div class='c1'>
    <div>child 1</div>
    <div>more content</div>
   </div>
  <div class='c2'>child 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: height 100vh is not what I want, it create scroll bar

Comment: "I want my c1 to be fully stretched" -- you have to define what that is. Is it 100vh? Is it 100 px?  The above answer is correct, just maybe a different number than 100vh.

Comment: @alice_morgan you feel free to change the hight or can you perhaps explain in more detail what exactly you expect?

Comment: I got it, just have to use box-sizing to not have a scroll bar